# Blogdown not rendering numeric lists in the correct order

Tags: r, markdown, blogdown

Say I type the following in a regular markdown file:

```
1. a
1. b
1. c
```

When rendered, it will display:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
```

For some reason, this doesn't happen in blogdown when using an Rmd file. Instead, it just renders the original order (a sequence of 1s), i.e., without the proper HTML tags. Any thoughts on why this might be the case?

Comment: You're telling us what _doesn't_ happen, which is a helpful part of a question. But it's not the whole story. What _does_ happen? Do you see three `1.`s? Are the values rendered as a proper `<ol>` containing `<li>`? Please see [ask].

Comment: @Chris I just addressed your question, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the update. Does this happen when the only content in your source file is what's shown in your question, or is there additional markup? And, again, are the results rendered as a proper `<ol>` containing `<li>`s? Sometimes indentation or similar can cause lists not to be rendered as lists.